# Gdb , how to use print?

Tags: debugging, gdb, sparc

can someone explain this "Also print out the contents of particular registers (use p) at key points in your program to show that it is working as expected. "?
I tried (gdb) p, but I keep getting "The history is empty

> (gdb) ni
>
> 0x000106d0 in loop ()
>
> 1: x/i $pc
>
> 0x106d0 :      call  0x2089c <.mul@plt>
>
> 0x106d4 :      mov  %l1, %o1
>
> (gdb) p
>
> The history is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ gdb -q ./output 
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400846: file test_lambda.cpp, line 11.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/mantosh/practice/notesofprogramming/gcc4.9/output 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main () at test_lambda.cpp:11
11      foo();
```

> //whenever you just type command "p", it checks for the last command
>   used. As we have
>        not used "p" anytime in our debug session for this particular program, it shows the
>        message "history is empty"//

```
(gdb) p
The history is empty.
```

> // This command would give the information about all registers

```
(gdb) info registers 
rax            0x7ffff73a3548   140737341175112
rbx            0x0  0
rcx            0x60 96
rdx            0x7fffffffe1b8   140737488347576
rsi            0x7fffffffe1a8   140737488347560
rdi            0x1  1
rbp            0x7fffffffe0c0   0x7fffffffe0c0
rsp            0x7fffffffe0c0   0x7fffffffe0c0
r8             0x7ffff7dd8240   140737351877184
r9             0x7ffff7dbddb0   140737351769520
r10            0x7fffffffddf0   140737488346608
r11            0x7ffff7023880   140737337505920
r12            0x4006f0 4196080
r13            0x7fffffffe1a0   140737488347552
r14            0x0  0
r15            0x0  0
rip            0x400846 0x400846 <main()+4>
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x33 51
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
```

> // Now we can print the rip(instruction pointer) using "p" command.
>   After this if we 
>       continue to debug our program, we can just type "p" and it would print about "rip"
>       as this is this was the argument passed in command "p" last time during the debug.

```
(gdb) p $rip
$1 = (void (*)(void)) 0x400846 <main()+4>
(gdb) step
foo () at test_lambda.cpp:4
4       int x = 10;
(gdb) p
$2 = (void (*)(void)) 0x400846 <main()+4>
(gdb) step
5       int y= 20;
(gdb) p
$3 = (void (*)(void)) 0x400846 <main()+4>
(gdb) n
6       x = x + y;
(gdb) p
$4 = (void (*)(void)) 0x400846 <main()+4>
(gdb) n
7       std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
(gdb) p
$5 = (void (*)(void)) 0x400846 <main()+4>
(gdb) c
Continuing.
30
[Inferior 1 (process 3226) exited normally]
(gdb)
```